# slideToggle only sliding down?

Tags: jquery, html

This one boggles my mind.  I've used this same script (different targets of course) on other elements in my script and it works perfectly.  Why, in this instance does the slideToggle only slide down?

Here is the hide, slideToggle code:

```
$('div.addLocation').hide();
$("p.buslocadd").click(function () {
    $(this).prev('div.addLocation').slideToggle(400);
    return false;
});
```

Here are the target elements:

```
<div class="addLocation"></div>
<p class="buslocadd"></p>
```

What's the deal?

Comment: I have no issue with the validity of the code.  I know it works on its own, and as you can see below, it works in testing environments as well.  My question remains, why might it *stop* working?  *I'm still trying to recreate the problem on jsbin.*

Comment: Have you hooked the event up twice maybe. Or have invalid markup...need to see the issue really

Comment: Also I would mark the below correct. You mention this instance in your question but the only context you provide is code that works...If you know its other things breaking it then you need to include the other stuff!!

Comment: Then re-ask the same question with context again?

Comment: well if you change the question the answers will look dumb no?

Comment: true, below will be marked correct, and question will be re-aseked.

Comment: I would mark nickf's answer since he was first up:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Works for me](http://jsbin.com/avawa).

Can you show some more code, or reproduce the error at jsbin.com?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me in this [pastebin.me demo](http://pastebin.me/4e982771169ee35f1907b87d64cd4fb5).